# Grounding nightmare

Tags: electrical, safety

Please don't laugh (too much), but maybe someone can tell if this is safe or not? It looks at best a total bodge job to me, and at worst downright dangerous, but I don't know what I'm on about to be honest.

My wife and I live in a pretty old building, not especially well maintained, and have been feeling very mild electric shocks from our bathroom sink. We called in an electrician (friend of a friend, but still a pro... apparently) to check it out. He said the problem probably wasn't originating in our apartment, but he couldn't know for sure without ripping the walls down. He did this (see images), and said it's a safe temporary solution. His idea, as far as I understood, was to ground the sink to the back of the washing machine.

I guess I should call in an actual pro right? Any advice would be much appreciated.

[image: Back of washing machine]

[image: Whatever you do, don't put your hand under the sink]

[image: Sticky tape will do the trick]

Comment: It looks like the sink drain connection is a flexible hose that is unlikely to carry a current.  That would mean that either the supply lines are hot (and the current is carried by the stainless braid) or that the sink is mounted to a current source, e.g. someone ran a screw into a cable. I can't tell whether the sink is metal or ceramic, but my guess would be that the supply lines are making the faucet "hot".

Comment: The sink is ceramic. What would you suggest we do?

Comment: Contact the building management and have them figure out why _their_ plumbing wants to kill you. In the meantime, don't touch the problem plumbing and label it so that no one else does. Aside: Note that unplugging the appliance (Washing machine?) removes the ground "connection".

Comment: @HABO agreed, grounding the drain seems worthless, like you said, most likely the supply. In fact, grounding the drain could make things worse.   If the supply is really hot, (not just leakage current), and the OP had one hand in the sink and the other on the faucet, that would be a direct path to ground "better" than before... but far worse for the OP. The house I grew up in had an electric water heater which became defective and leaked current into the supply.  The house had an old fuse panel (Yes actual fuses), poor grounding and we'd get shocked at times at the kitchen sink. ...continued.

Comment: ...continued from above.  As a brilliant young electrical engineer at about age 12 (LOL, kidding), I fixed it by connecting the supply to the metal (galvanized) drain line. Yeah, it was also a hack, but we had little money to hire an electrician. Eventually replaced the water heater and main panel when my dad's business became more successful.

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestions. I'm keeping the appliances disconnected for now, and will wait for a professional to come check it out.

Answer (score 1):

No!  That's not safe at all.  Please disconnect power to the application at the panel and call for a qualified and licensed electrician to sort this out.

I'm especially concerned by the routing of the dubious ground wire along the edge of what looks like your shower.  If that gets "HOT" due to some fault and you drip some water, it may be lethal!

Comment: Yes it's our shower. I've disconnected the washing machine and all other electrical appliances in the bathroom, and will call an electrician now. Thanks.

Comment: Deleted previous version of this comment bc I was wrong. It is dangerous but not why jwh20 said. See my above comment on the OP. The dubious ground wire is at least insulated. But as I said above, grounding the sink drain could make it worse.  And jwh20, you are right, a real pro electrician will need to sort this out.